# Share Screen with Chromium: Black Screen

Tags: snap, chromium, wayland, screencast

If I want to share the screen in Chromium, I see only black screens.

I can share the screen, but the other participants only see a black screen.

Sharing a window or chromium tab works fine.

I use Ubuntu 21.10

[image: chromium-share-screen]

Is there a way to make sharing a screen work again?

It is not related to microsoft-teams, since it is the same issue if I use the web version of slack.

```
Chromium    95.0.4638.69 (Offizieller Build) snap (64-Bit)
Überarbeitung   6a1600ed572fedecd573b6c2b90a22fe6392a410-refs/branch-heads/4638@{#984}
Betriebssystem  Linux
JavaScript  V8 9.5.172.25
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.69 Safari/537.36
Befehlszeile    /snap/chromium/1810/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome --password-store=basic --flag-switches-begin --flag-switches-end --origin-trial-disabled-features=CaptureHandle
Programmdateipfad   /snap/chromium/1810/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome
Profilpfad  /home/guettli/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default
Varianten   c4c83305-6ce6e1ee
```

Comment: You're not using Wayland, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 21.10 uses Wayland by default. Wayland is still being actively developed, and certain features like screen sharing do not function properly.

In your login screen, you can switch to the "Ubuntu"/"Ubuntu on X.Org" session, and screen sharing should work there.

[image]
 <sup>Image source: [OMG! Ubuntu!](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/01/ubuntu-21-04-will-use-wayland-by-default)</sup>

Comment: After logging in again without Wayland it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: I haven't tested your solution, but I have tried sharing my screen in Firefox, and that works /fine/ on Ubuntu with Wayland. I am not completely satisfied with this answer. Perhaps it is a bug on the side of Chrome/Chromium?

Comment: And indeed, moving to "Ubuntu XORG" fixes it, but why has Firefox a working method, and Chrom(e|ium) not ;)

Comment: May it have something to do with the permission restrictions of snap? So that Chromium is not allowed to access the Wayland resources necessary to share anything outside of itself?

Comment: @TorstenBronger No it's not about snap. Wayland disables the ability of one app to see other apps (and the whole screen) for the sake of security, but here it becomes a bug rather than a feature.