# Black Screen during Screen Share in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: screen, 21.10

Whenever I share my screen it always shows as a black screen with my cursor to other people in the meeting. It doesn't matter which platform I am using be it Slack, Google Meet, Zoom, or any other.

OS - UBUNTU 21.10
Graphics Card - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

I tried this [Share Screen with Chromium: Black Screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1377325/share-screen-with-chromium-black-screen),
But there was no option for my pc to switch between Wayland.

I also tried this [Black Screen during Screen Share in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1270710/black-screen-during-screen-share-in-ubuntu-18-04), But after this three-finger screen switch stopped working.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, if you want to use a more stable OS, 20.04 LTS is less problematic and you can try 22.04 LTS later. 21.10 like half-year span series are more less test versions having thousands of bugs waiting to dig out. It's a good opportunity to learn but you don't want to be interfered every week.

Answer (score 2):

Wayland is enabled by default in the Ubuntu 21.10 installation. The goal is to disable Wayland and instead use the Xorg display server.

It's possible that you'll need to change the GDM3 custom configuration file.

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

By uncommenting this, the login screen will be forced to use Xorg.

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

Restart the computer after you've made the modifications. It was successful for me!